Estou com um problema em uma requisição
Em meu código estou tentando listar os comentários presentes em uma tabela, em uma página estou fazendo tal requisição:
    fetch("/comentarios/listar", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            idPubServer: idPubVar
        }),
    }).then(function (resposta) {
        if (resposta.ok) {
            if (resposta.status == 204) {
                var feed = document.getElementById("feed_container");
                var mensagem = document.createElement("span");
                mensagem.innerHTML = "Nenhum comentário."
                feed.appendChild(mensagem);
                throw "Nenhum comentário!!";
            }

            resposta.json().then(function (resposta) {
                console.log("Dados recebidos: ", JSON.stringify(resposta));

            })
            var feed = document.getElementById("feed_container");
            feed.innerHTML = "";
            for (let index = 0; index < resposta.length; index++) {
                var comentario = resposta[index]

                var divComentario = document.createElement("div");
                var spanNome = document.createElement("span")
                var textComentario = document.createElemen("textarea");

                spanNome.innerHTML = "ID: <b>" + comentario.nome;
                textComentario.innerHTML = comentario.comentario;



            }
        }
    })
}

Ao passar pela controler:
function listar(req, res) {
var idPub = req.body.idPubServer;;

comentarioModel.listar(idPub)
    .then(function (resultado) {
    if (resultado.length > 0) {
        res.status(200).json(resultado);
    } else {
        res.status(204).send("Nenhum resultado encontrado!")
    }
}).catch(function (erro) {
    console.log(erro);
    console.log("Houve um erro ao buscar os avisos: ", erro.sqlMessage);
    res.status(500).json(erro.sqlMessage);
});

}
A idPubServer simplesmente fica nula e por consequência não é possível realizar o select no banco, alguém pode me ajudar?

No lado servidor se você fizer console.log(req.body); qual o resultado? Ainda no servidor, seu código está usando o middleware apropriado para analisar solicitações recebidas com payload JSON, EX: app.use(express.json()); ?

Seu erro pode estar acontecendo porque a variável idPub está sendo passada como null para a função comentarioModel.listar. Isso tá impedindo a realização do select no banco de dados.
Vc pode verificar se a váriável está vazia ou indefinida antes de passá-la para a função para contornar esse erro.
